# Multiple binding of child routes with angular new router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a project with the new angular router and have run into an issue where my child routes get bound multiple times. Here is a quick example showing the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pZ25uCxHu5O5BcBcDbrO?p=preview

Basic navigation controls and viewport in the index.html

```
<md-continer layout="row">
  <a ng-link="one()">One</a> 
  &nbsp; | &nbsp;
  <a ng-link="two()">Two</a>
</md-continer>
<div ng-viewport></div>
```

Once I add this viewport to page two, the code in both controllers starts repeating itself.

```
<div ng-viewport></div>
```

Each component controller has a console.log when it is loaded. If you watch your console when switching between components and one of them contains its own ng-viewport, you will start to get duplicate logs from the controller. When I remove the component ng-viewport, the error stops. Does anybody have any experience with this?

Comment: Is it important that neither of these viewports have names (and thus both are implicitly named 'default')?

Comment: I run into the issue when they both have names. I don't think it matters because, and I could be mistaken, the current controller scopes to itself so it understands its own root scope and viewport

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might have hit this issue;https://github.com/angular/router/issues/204 which is currently open against the new router, and references a couple of similar issues that may be worth you checking as well. If not, you could log a new issue with your example, it looks like the team are active at looking at issues logged on github